# there is a type mismatch error in this sub procedure,can anyone help me

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2003

```
Private Sub cmdenter_Click()
     If Option1.Value = True Then
        db.Execute "Insert into TM_REGISTRATION values('" + txtregdn.Text + "','" + txtformno.Text + "','" + Combo1.Text + "','" + Format(mskadmdt.Text, "mm-dd-yyyy") + "','" + studentname.Text + "','" + Combo2.Text + "','" + fname.Text + "','" + fmobile.Text + "','" + mname.Text + "','" + mmobile.Text + "','" + gname.Text + "','" + gmobile.Text + "','" + Format(mskdob.Text, "mm-dd-yyyy") + "',1,0,'" + Combo3.Text + "','" + Combo4.Text + "','" + Combo5.Text + "','" + Combo6.Text + "','" + txtaddress1.Text + "','" + txtaddress2.Text + "','" + district.Text + "','" + pincode.Text + "','" + Picture1.Picture + "')"
     ElseIf Option2.Value = True Then
        db.Execute "Insert into TM_REGISTRATION values('" + txtregdn.Text + "','" + txtformno.Text + "','" + Combo1.Text + "','" + Format(mskadmdt.Text, "mm-dd-yyyy") + "','" + studentname.Text + "','" + Combo2.Text + "','" + fname.Text + "','" + fmobile.Text + "','" + mname.Text + "','" + mmobile.Text + "','" + gname.Text + "','" + gmobile.Text + "','" + Format(mskdob.Text, "mm-dd-yyyy") + "',0,1,'" + Combo3.Text + "','" + Combo4.Text + "','" + Combo5.Text + "','" + Combo6.Text + "','" + txtaddress1.Text + "','" + txtaddress2.Text + "','" + district.Text + "','" + pincode.Text + "','" + Picture1.Picture + "')"
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: What is the exact error message you receive? Is it from VB6 or is it from Access?

Answer (score 0):

Columns are missing.

SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Answer (score 0):

Format the date value expressions correctly:

```
db.Execute "Insert into TM_REGISTRATION values('" + txtregdn.Text + "','" + txtformno.Text + "','" + Combo1.Text + "',#" + Format(mskadmdt.Text, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") + "#,'" + studentname.Text + "','" + Combo2.Text + "','" + fname.Text + "','" + fmobile.Text + "','" + mname.Text + "','" + mmobile.Text + "','" + gname.Text + "','" + gmobile.Text + "',#" + Format(mskdob.Text, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") + "#,1,0,'" + Combo3.Text + "','" + Combo4.Text + "','" + Combo5.Text + "','" + Combo6.Text + "','" + txtaddress1.Text + "','" + txtaddress2.Text + "','" + district.Text + "','" + pincode.Text + "','" + Picture1.Picture + "')"
```